# Method must have a return type (C#)

Tags: c#, button, back, forward

Been getting a "Method must have a return type, and i don't really understand why.

It is the "public HelpView()" part that returns the error. (Top of code, made it into a block quote)

Web browser application, code is for back and forward buttons.

```
public class HelpView
    {

    }
    List<Uri> HistoryStack;
int HistoryStack_Index;
bool fromHistory;

 //Constructor
public HelpView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    HistoryStack = new List<Uri>();
    HistoryStack_Index = 0;
    fromHistory = false;
    webBrowser1.Navigated += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs>(webBrowser1_Navigated);
    updateNavButtons();
}
```

Comment: Is your class named `helpView`? Case matters in C# and `helpView` is different from `HelpView`. If your class is named `HelpView` then `helpView` is *not* recognized as a constructor but a normal method that must have a return type

Comment: The original code was with HelpView, not helpView. Just something i tested and forgot about. Same result with both capital and non capital H

Comment: Don't include tags in the question title. Don't post more code than is relevant (those forward and back methods don't need to be included). Do include your class definition (the bit with `class xxxxxx`).

Comment: please add the code where the class name is defined

Comment: @musefan First time i ask a question here, sorry

Comment: @user3303633: It's not a problem, just giving you some tips. Please include the class definition, it is the key to providing a correct answer. Constructors need to be named exactly the same as the class, you obviously intend it to be a constructor for several reasons (no return type, the comment says so, and generally that is where `InitializeComponent` call would be made)

Comment: @musefan Either i do not have it, or I cant find it. I assume it shoud be in "Form1.cs" with the rest of the code. If i do not have it, how should i correctly type it in and where should i place it?

Comment: @user3303633: I have added an answer with a complete class example.

Comment: In the code sample of your question you open and close the brackets of the HelpView class. The HelpView() method is outside the HelpView class. Do you have it exactly the same in your code?

Answer (score 3):

helpview is likely not the exact name of your class.  If this is meant to be the constructor, make sure the method name matches your class name.  If this is meant to be a method, change it to

```
public void helpView()
```

Comment: Sorry, the code is `public void HelpView()` i tried changing capitalitation and forgot to change back before i posted here.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that compilation error is occuring is because the compiler thinks you are trying to create a method, and methods need to have a return type (or `void`). The only time you don't need a return type is when you have a constructor, however the rule of constructors is that they must have the exact same name as the class. As you don't have the same name, this is why the compiler is validating it like a method.

The solution is to make sure the constructor name and the class name are exactly the same.

---

In response to a comment from the OP asking for the class definition (and the reason why I have posted an answer at all), this is what your valid class and constructor should look like.

Note that **CLASS NAME** and **CONSTRUCTOR NAME** must be exactly the same.

```
public class HelpView // <- CLASS NAME
{
    // Properties.
    List<Uri> HistoryStack;
    int HistoryStack_Index;
    bool fromHistory;

    // Constructor.
    public HelpView() // <- CONSTRUCTOR NAME
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HistoryStack = new List<Uri>();
        HistoryStack_Index = 0;
        fromHistory = false;
        webBrowser1.Navigated += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs>(webBrowser1_Navigated);
        updateNavButtons();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just changed code to what you suggested so current code is edited into original question.
Same error..

Comment: @user3303633: That isn't the same, your code must go **inside** of the class { }. I would also recommend that once you have resolved this you find some basic tutorials on C# and work through some of those to help get you started, you are missing some very basic knowledge at the moment

Comment: I have gone through some basic tutorials, and feel like i shoud know this, either way, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

If we refer to the code currently used in your post, then the position of the curly brackets seems to be off. You open them for your `HelpView` class and it's closed right after.

It should rather be :

```
public class HelpView
{
    List<Uri> HistoryStack;
    int HistoryStack_Index;
    bool fromHistory;

    //Constructor
    public HelpView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HistoryStack = new List<Uri>();
        HistoryStack_Index = 0;
        fromHistory = false;
        webBrowser1.Navigated += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs>(webBrowser1_Navigated);
        updateNavButtons();
    }
}
```

Comment: New error further down in the code when i do that. " The type or namespace name 'Navigation' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?) "

Comment: It looks like you have to add a reference to PresentationFramework.dll in order to use System.Windows.Navigation